# Java como criar um linha de comando personalizada

Tags: java, terminal

Ola pessoal queria sabe se tem como personalizar a linha de comando...
basicamente criar uma linha personalizada no console

Eu tenho um código que cria um terminal capaz de suportar cores (Windows e Unix) via o "Ansi", e queria adicionar a marcação ">" antes de um comando (lembrar o console do Spigot do Minecraft)

Exemplo:
[image: Exemplo do console do minecraft]

A parte do [Horario nivel]: StringInforamtiva é enviada ao console via o `System.out.println();`

Comment: Criar uma interface de linha de comando?

Comment: [Liberar apenas a última linha para escrita](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/137916/28595)

Comment: Isso mesmo obrigado